# Bash foreach from array and append result in next iteration

Tags: bash, foreach

How display each line in array with previous iteration result?
Like this example: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,A,B,C,D,E,F,J,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z,1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F ....etc

Please help!

My code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env bash

    STRINGS=( 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z )
    str=""

    more() {
        echo $str;
        # run again each()
    }

    each() {
        for i in "${STRINGS[@]}"
        do
            echo $i
            str="${i}";
        done
        more;
    }

    each;
```

Comment: Can you make your sample input and output more precise? And what do you mean by "append result in next iteration"? For example, do you want something like `0` then `0 1` then `0 1 2` then `0 1 2 3` etc?

Comment: If you start with `STRINGS=( x y )`, for example, what is the full expected output.

Answer (score 1):

here you go...

```
$ echo {0..9} {A..Z} {1..9}{A..Z}
```

> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y
>   Z 1A 1B 1C 1D 1E 1F 1G 1H 1I 1J 1K 1L 1M 1N 1O 1P 1Q 1R 1S 1T 1U 1V 1W
>   1X 1Y 1Z 2A 2B 2C 2D 2E 2F 2G 2H 2I 2J 2K 2L 2M 2N 2O 2P 2Q 2R 2S 2T
>   2U 2V 2W 2X 2Y 2Z 3A 3B 3C 3D 3E 3F 3G 3H 3I 3J 3K 3L 3M 3N 3O 3P 3Q
>   3R 3S 3T 3U 3V 3W 3X 3Y 3Z 4A 4B 4C 4D 4E 4F 4G 4H 4I 4J 4K 4L 4M 4N
>   4O 4P 4Q 4R 4S 4T 4U 4V 4W 4X 4Y 4Z 5A 5B 5C 5D 5E 5F 5G 5H 5I 5J 5K
>   5L 5M 5N 5O 5P 5Q 5R 5S 5T 5U 5V 5W 5X 5Y 5Z 6A 6B 6C 6D 6E 6F 6G 6H
>   6I 6J 6K 6L 6M 6N 6O 6P 6Q 6R 6S 6T 6U 6V 6W 6X 6Y 6Z 7A 7B 7C 7D 7E
>   7F 7G 7H 7I 7J 7K 7L 7M 7N 7O 7P 7Q 7R 7S 7T 7U 7V 7W 7X 7Y 7Z 8A 8B
>   8C 8D 8E 8F 8G 8H 8I 8J 8K 8L 8M 8N 8O 8P 8Q 8R 8S 8T 8U 8V 8W 8X 8Y
>   8Z 9A 9B 9C 9D 9E 9F 9G 9H 9I 9J 9K 9L 9M 9N 9O 9P 9Q 9R 9S 9T 9U 9V
>   9W 9X 9Y 9Z

if you want comma separated pipe into `tr ' ' ','`

Comment: It's not clear if this is what the OP wanted, but we may never know what the OP wanted.  Upvoted because it is a very nice demonstration of Bash "sequence expressions".